# New tweetdeck custom launcher to run under unity 11.10

Tags: unity, launcher, wine, twitter

I am looking to create a custom launcher for the new tweetdeck (which works fine under wine).

I am currently just executing the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
wine  ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Twitter/TweetDeck/TweetDeck.exe
```

But this has the nasty disadvantage that you cannot close the terminal that spawned the window.

Has anyone made a custom launcher for unity (with the new icon would be nice)?

Comment: Any reason you can't use [tweetdeck extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hbdpomandigafcibbmofojjchbcdagbl?hl=en-US) in google chrome?

Comment: This requires you to run chrome ;) But yes, this is a nice alternative

Answer (score 1):

Just add nohup and an & to that command

```
nohup wine  ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Twitter/TweetDeck/TweetDeck.exe > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Probably best to use the full path with those commands, so /home/your_user rather then ~

Then make a custom launcher with that command.